# ColdFusion - Variable SESSION is Undefined

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I'm getting the above error message.

I have a CF app that uses application.cfc - users access the app with a DNS name - myapp.usps.gov
It currently is on a Win2008 server with Websphere - all works fine.
I migrated the CF app to a Win2016 server using Tomcat - just trying to access the login page gives me the error message:  Variable SESSION is Undefined.  So the call is failing at the application.cfc level.
FYI - if you use the IP address in the URL instead of the DNS name, all works well.
Another FYI - I have another app that uses application.cfm, and calling it with DNS name works fine on same platform.
Any suggestions as where to look at in the application.cfc file would be helpful.

Comment: Is `sessionManagement` set in the application.cfc? Did you check if any Administrator settings are different from the old version?

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on?  If so, do you see any session variables?

Comment: Yes, sessionManagement is set - <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>

Comment: Yes, sessionManagement is set - <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>.  Is there a specific setting I need to check in CF Admin on our older CF2008 version?   I don't have access to our Prod environment so I would have to ask an engineer to review it.

Comment: As for debugging, it's turned on, but all I'm getting is the CF error screen.  I believe it's because my call is immediately erroring because the application.cfc is complaining about something it's not receiving.  The error message I'm getting is in from a "onError" function, which means that I'm erroring right away, before the session variables are getting set, in my view.  Let me know if I need to review any CF2016 Admin settings.

Comment: So you migrated this app to a new OS and a new servlet container. Did you also upgrade the version of ColdFusion and/or Java? You mentioned "on our older CF2008 version", what version are you using now? Have you removed content from the `Application.cfc` to grind down to what line is throwing the error?

Comment: We are using CF2016.  I have also been removing content from application.cfc to determine what's causing the error to happen. But actually I have come across new info.

Comment: I found out that when you open your browser in "InPrivate Browsing" mode or Incognito mode, the login page displays fine.  When not in those modes, you get the error page.  Any ideas on why this is so?